# Finding derivative of three variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider a box with dimensions x, y, and z. x is changing at a rate of 1 m/s, y at -2 m/s and z at 1 m/s. Find the rate that the volume, surface area and diagonal length ($s = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$) are changing at the instant when $x = 4$, $y = 3$ and $z = 2$.

I know I need to use to product rule. But my teacher didn't bother to teach it to us how to do it with three variables (ex. xyz for the volume). So I'm having trouble figuring out how to start this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write out your equations for volume, surface area, and diagonal length and take the derivative with respect to time. I assume you have gone over this in class, but for the surface area it should look like:

$\frac{d}{dt}s(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial s}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial s}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial s}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$. Then, you have equations for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ etc. From there it is just plug and chug.

Comment: thanks for your reply!for surface area of the box you would do _SA_ = _2XY_ + _2XZ_ + _2YZ_ right? so wouldn't the derivative of that be _2XY'_ + _2X'Y_ + _2XZ'_ + _2X'Z_ + _2YZ'_ + _2Y'Z_? And then how would you find the derivative of the volume? We didn't go over how to find the derivative using the product rule of 3 variables multiplied together.

Comment: That looks correct. For $V=xyz$, you have $\frac{dV}{dt} = yz\frac{dx}{dt}$ etc. It is of the same form as what I did above. Can you complete the rest? When you take partials you consider the other variables to be constants.

Comment: So just to make sure im understanding you correctly it would be _V' = YZX' + XZY' + XYZ'_ ? And then for the diagonal would you use chain rule (_2XX'_) for the inside part or just the power rule (_2X_)?

Comment: The volume derivative is correct. You would use the chain rule, the x component would look like: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Comment: where did the X in the numerator come from? Would you do the chain rule on the whole square root and get _2X + 2Y + 2Z/(2 * sqrt(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2))_ ?

Comment: Not quite. When you take a partial the other terms get treated as constants, remember that. $\frac{\partial s}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2} 2x (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1/2}$ because $y$ and $z$ are constant, right?

By the way Morgan, it might be helpful for you to look up some TeX commands to make your posts easier to read. For example, if you want $x^2$, you can type \$x^2\$.

Comment: oh ok so you do that for every term? Yeah I know sorry about that. First post on here and I'm still trying to get the hang of it all. I tried clicking on the help button but couldn't see how you were doing the equations.

Comment: It's okay, I thought I would let you know for future posts, everyone has to learn sometime! Yes, you would do that for every term, taking the derivative with respect to the different values, they should all look similar with a different denominator. Do you get this?

Comment: Yeah I think I got it. Would they have a different denominators or numerators? I was expecting there to be a different numerator.

Comment: Sorry, this is what I meant. Good catch.

Comment: Not a problem. Just shows I really did understand what you meant which is a good sign. Thank you for all your help and patience Jeremy! This was all a huge help for me

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to find the derivative of a product of $2$ terms, you can find the derivative of the product of any number of terms.

For example, let us find $(xyz)'$.  So we want to find the derivative of the product $(xy)z$ of **two** terms.

By the product rule for two terms, the derivative is $(xy)z'+(xy)'z$.  Applying the two variable product rule to $(xy)'$, we get that our derivative is
$$(xy)z' +(xy'+x'y)z,$$
that is,
$$xyz'+xy'z+x'yz.$$

In the same way, one finds that the derivative of $wxyz$ is
$$wxyz'+wxy'z+wx'yz+w'xyz.$$
The obvious pattern continues for a product of $5$ terms, $6$, and so on.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas. Thank you so much!that made a lot of sense where that comes from. I'd give you an up vote but I don't have enough reputations but this was a big help.

Comment: You are welcome. For the product of $wxyz$, think of it as $(wxy)z$. You know how to do a product of $2$, and a product of $3$, so you can combine to find the derivative of a product of $4$.

Comment: Nicolas Makes perfect sense now. Saved me a big head ache tonight